# PWM DAC, dividing the 8 bit PWM DAC in 2 four bit PWM DAC

Tags: pwm, dac, resolution

Can anybody explain what the purpose is of dividing an 8 bit DAC using PWM in two 4 bits DAC and how is it made possible the scaling of PWMH and PWML and how do they affect in total uncertainty.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt795/slyt795.pdf?ts=1686278850434&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of dividing is to reduce the PWM frequency and clock frequency required to achieve a high-resolution output.
By using two PWM signals with different scales (PWMH and PWML), the effective resolution can be increased without increasing the PWM frequency.
**The scaling of PWMH and PWML is done by using different values of resistors** in a voltage divider circuit that combines the two PWM outputs into one analog output.
The total uncertainty of the output depends on the accuracy of the resistors, the PWM duty cycle, and the filter characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is exactly what Im  having difficulties to understand "the effective resolution can be increased without increasing the PWM frequency".
Let's take the example on the paper , we want to make an 8 bit PWM using two 4 bits PWM output.We scale the output of PWM in order so it's 2^4 larger than pwml (bcs of 4 bits) , resolution of each of 4 bits pwm will be 2^4 , so the smallest change will be Vref /2^4  in confront of Vref/ 2^8 it was before
how did we increase the resolution ?